# Set visual focus on item in QGraphicsview

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

just a short question, does any one of you know how to set a visual focus on an item, that has been placed in the QGraphicsview, so that the view is centered around that item?

In my particular example, I'm constructing a Stacklayout, where I add QGraphicsRectItems into a scene, and I essentially want, that the view always focuses on the latest added item, right now it remains at the same position and I have to scroll down manually, setfocusItem doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Will [`QGraphicsView::ensureVisible`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#ensureVisible-3) do?

Comment: The description sounds like it should, but currently it seems not to work, are there any flags or something like that, that have to be set, so that works?